# Sort multidimensional array by different values conditionally

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have the next multidimensioanl array (It's quite longer, but I copy here the first elements):

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [cpt] => Product
        [tax] => Type A
        [year] => 2012
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [cpt] => Product
        [tax] => Type B
        [year] => 2012
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [cpt] => Product
        [tax] => Type C
        [year] => 2011
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [cpt] => Product
        [tax] => Type C
        [year] => 2011
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [cpt] => Product
        [tax] => Type D
        [year] => 2015
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [cpt] => Review
        [tax] => Figure
        [year] => 2014
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [cpt] => Review
        [tax] => Sample
        [year] => 2012
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [cpt] => Review
        [tax] => Figure
        [year] => 2012
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [cpt] => Review
        [tax] => Picture based
        [year] => 2015
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [cpt] => Review
        [tax] => Figure
        [year] => 2012
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [cpt] => Review
        [tax] => Picture based
        [year] => 2013
    )
[11] => Array
    (
        [cpt] => Template
        [tax] => L
        [year] => 2013
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [cpt] => Template
        [tax] => L
        [year] => 2015
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [cpt] => Template
        [tax] => M
        [year] => 2011
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [cpt] => Template
        [tax] => S
        [year] => 2011
    )
```

And I need to sort it first by the "cpt" value, then by the "tax" value, and finally by the "year".

The problem is that the sorting order for "cpt" and "tax" should be a custom order, not alphabetically.

And the good news are:

- The array always is generated perfectly sorted by "cpt" (as you can
  see). So I don't care about sorting it.
- I only need to apply these sorting changes (in "tax" first, and
  "year" next) for a specific "cpt", that is "Review".

This is my code, but it's not valid, because it changes the "cpt" order also.

```
$sort_tax = array("Sample","Figure","Picture based");
usort($the_array, function ($a, $b) use ($sort_tax) {
    $pos_a = array_search($a['tax'], $sort_tax);
    $pos_b = array_search($b['tax'], $sort_tax);
    $result = $pos_a - $pos_b;
    if ($result == 0) {
        $difference = $a['year'] - $b['year'];
        if ($difference >= 0) {
            $value = 0;
        } else {
            $value = 1;
        }
        return $value;
    } else {
        return $pos_a - $pos_b;
    }
});
```

Any ideas?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array();
foreach($array_name as $arr){
  $array['cpt'] = $arr['cpt'];
  $array['tax'] = $arr['tax'];
  $array['year'] = $arr['year'];
} 

array_multisort($array['tax'], SORT_DESC, $array['year'], SORT_ASC,$Your_array_name);
```

You can check array_multisort from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Comment: As I wrote on the question: _The problem is that the sorting order for "cpt" and "tax" should be a custom order, not alphabetically_